# Macro will not perform properly if any cell is clicked in sheet prior to running

Tags: excel, vba, macos, excel-2010

I created a simple macro to format a report.

If I open the file and do not click any cell or anywhere in the active spreadsheet, then run the macro, the macro executes flawlessly,

If I open the file and make even one click, the macro does not autofit my first row and columns.  Literally one click, and my results are not achieved.

I need to fix this. I am not sure if it is due to a selection or if it's an active sheet issue.

```
'Unmerge all Cells in Worksheet 
ActiveSheet.Cells.UnMerge 

'Delete Columns A1 thru D1 
Range("A1:D1").EntireColumn.Delete 

'Delete Rows A1 thru A9 
Range("A1:A9").EntireRow.Delete 

'Cut and Paste Cells 
Range("A2").Cut Range("A1") 
Range("G1").Cut Range("F1") 
Range("P1").Cut Range("O1") 
Range("AA1").Cut Range("Z1") 

'Sort by Column A to Remove Extra Rows from View 
Columns("A:AM").Sort key1:=Range("A:A"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes 

'Auto Fit Contents in Columns and Rows 
ActiveCell.Columns("A:AG").EntireColumn.Select 
ActiveCell.Columns("A:AG").EntireColumn.AutoFit 
ActiveSheet.Rows.EntireRow.AutoFit 

'Delete Empty Columns 
Range("B:B, D:D, G:I, K:L, N:N, P:Q, T:V, X:Y, AA:AB, AD:AF").EntireColumn.Delete 

'Remove Wrap Text from Cell B1 
Range("B1").WrapText = False 

'Autofit Contents of Columns 
Range("A1:AF1").Columns.AutoFit 

'Autofit Row A2 Contents 
Range("A2:A2").Rows.AutoFit 

'Save File As 
Application.GetSaveAsFilename
```

Answer (score 0):

This block looks wrong to me:

```
'Auto Fit Contents in Columns and Rows 
ActiveCell.Columns("A:AG").EntireColumn.Select 
ActiveCell.Columns("A:AG").EntireColumn.AutoFit 
ActiveSheet.Rows.EntireRow.AutoFit
```

Try changing ActiveCell to ActiveSheet:

```
'Auto Fit Contents in Columns and Rows 
ActiveSheet.Columns("A:AG").EntireColumn.Select 
ActiveSheet.Columns("A:AG").EntireColumn.AutoFit 
ActiveSheet.Rows.EntireRow.AutoFit
```

(Because you are using relative references rather than absolute references, ActiveCell.Columns("A:AG") will be relative to whichever cell you happen to click, rather than starting from the worksheet's origin)

Comment: Thank you. Made that change, it seems to longer effect the header row, but it now is not sorting to remove blanks if cell with header row is selected. Ughh..  Im thinking, do I just change this so the first step is to select A1, a column that doesnt have any value, and appears to not influence the end result? ... I really would not like to work around it crudely, but instead, understand what I did wrong so programmatically I do not make further errors like this as I learn to write these macros

Comment: OK - so here are some suggestions around making your code more robust:  
1. Learn about the difference between relative and absolute references in Excel (ref: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Switch-between-relative-absolute-and-mixed-references-dfec08cd-ae65-4f56-839e-5f0d8d0baca9)  
2. Learn how to use the Range object in Excel VBA (ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx) - especially how to use the Cells notation (as the article recommends)  
This will make your program much less prone to the kind of problems you are experiencing.

Comment: Although I appreciate what your saying, it will always be the same rows and columns needing to be deleted, which is why I didnt make it more dynamic. I could use exact references.  The only issue is, when a user clicks anywhere in the sheet, it causes things to get messed up, but only in the autofit segment. Everything else executes flawlessly. I will review the information you attached, I appreciate the tip :), I agree I will be spending more time learning this.  I didnt name a range because the columns will always be the same, the amount of rows will be variable each month depending on amoun

Comment: You don't have to use named ranges, or the Range object, but you ought to make your references absolute. Just put the dollar sign in front, and then the user clicking won't affect Excel's decision about what cell you are referring to. So $B:$B is always Column B, but B:B is the column to the right of the one the user has just clicked in. That is why things are messing up. Hope that helps, Ben